# FOP failing to use data when used with JAXB

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb2, apache-fop

I'm generating a document using FOP (0.95) by passing a source XML file created using JAXB (2.2.13), when I run it I get a virtually empty PDF (it looks like I'd expect if no data was supplied in the source XML) and the only log output is:

```
DEBUG [FOP] target-resolution set to: 72.0dpi (px2mm=0.35277778)
INFO [org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableLayoutManager] table-layout="fixed" and width="auto", but auto-layout not supported => assuming width="100%"
WARN [org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreakingAlgorithm] Part/page 0 overflows the available area in block-progression dimension. (fo:static-content, no context info available)
```

but if I comment out the line

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.blah.com/ctms/Comparison")
```

in the package-info.java file generated from my XSD by JAXB and recompile then the PDF generates fine.

Is there an obvious change I need to make so that I can use the generated JAXB code without editing anything, or alternatively some debugging I can enable to see what is happening?

My XSD is:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:pi="http://www.blah.com/ctms/Comparison" targetNamespace="http://www.blah.com/ctms/Comparison" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="comparison">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Document containing comparison data for report</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="sub-category" type="pi:sub-category" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="import-id" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="row-no" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="investigator-no" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="clinical-personnel-name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="report-footer-message" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="checklist" type="pi:checklist" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="properties" type="pi:properties" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="field-type">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="importValue" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="existingValue" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="record-type">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="field" type="pi:field-type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="sub-category">
    <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="record" type="pi:record-type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="checklist">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="checklist-no" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="checklist-title" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="checklist-description" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="checklist-status" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="completed-by" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="completed-date" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="question-item" type="pi:question-item" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="question-item">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="item-desc" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="response" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="item-no" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

and the following is an example of the generated XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:comparison xmlns:ns2="http://www.blah.com/ctms/Comparison">
    <sub-category name="Specialist Fields">
        <record>
            <field name="Specialist Field">
                <importValue>Adult Endocrinologist [AE]</importValue>
                <existingValue>Adult Endocrinologist [AE]</existingValue>
            </field>
            <field name="Key Opinion Leader">
                <importValue></importValue>
                <existingValue>No</existingValue>
            </field>
            <field name="Board Certification">
                <importValue></importValue>
                <existingValue>Yes</existingValue>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record>
            <field name="Specialist Field">
                <importValue>Cardiac Surgeon [CS]</importValue>
                <existingValue>Cardiac Surgeon [CS]</existingValue>
            </field>
            <field name="Key Opinion Leader">
                <importValue></importValue>
                <existingValue>No</existingValue>
            </field>
            <field name="Board Certification">
                <importValue>No</importValue>
                <existingValue>Yes</existingValue>
            </field>
        </record>
    </sub-category>
    <sub-category name="Clinical Personnel Address">
        <record>
            <field>
                <importValue>2-Line 1</importValue>
                <importValue>Florida [US-FL]</importValue>
                <importValue>United States of America [USA]</importValue>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record>
            <field>
                <existingValue>Line 1</existingValue>
                <existingValue>Florida [US-FL]</existingValue>
                <existingValue>United States of America [USA]</existingValue>
            </field>
        </record>
    </sub-category>
    <sub-category name="Membership Information">
        <record>
            <field name="Association/Society">
                <importValue>The Dennis the Menace Fan Club</importValue>
            </field>
            <field>
                <existingValue>Tufty Club</existingValue>
            </field>
        </record>
    </sub-category>
    <sub-category name="Centre">
        <record>
            <field name="Centre">
                <existingValue>Centre Name 313</existingValue>
                <existingValue>Address Line 1 for Cneter 313</existingValue>
                <existingValue>Address Line 2 for Cneter 313</existingValue>
                <existingValue>Address Line 3 for Cneter 313</existingValue>
                <existingValue>Address Line 4 for Cneter 313</existingValue>
                <existingValue>Centre Town City 313</existingValue>
                <existingValue>P_C 313</existingValue>
                <existingValue>ZZ Country CA0................ [CA0]</existingValue>
            </field>
            <field>
                <existingValue>Centre Name 312</existingValue>
                <existingValue>Address Line 1 for Cneter 312</existingValue>
                <existingValue>Address Line 2 for Cneter 312</existingValue>
                <existingValue>Address Line 3 for Cneter 312</existingValue>
                <existingValue>Address Line 4 for Cneter 312</existingValue>
                <existingValue>Centre Town City 312</existingValue>
                <existingValue>P_C 312</existingValue>
                <existingValue>ZZ Country CA0................ [CA0]</existingValue>
            </field>
        </record>
        <message>The system identified 2 Centres as being a potential match to the imported Centre details and therefore both the imported Centre and each Centre associated to the existing Clinical Personnel is listed below.</message>
    </sub-category>
    <sub-category name="Clinical Personnel">
        <record>
            <field name="Investigator Alias Code">
                <importValue>5656</importValue>
                <existingValue>545</existingValue>
            </field>
            <field name="Title">
                <existingValue>Mrs</existingValue>
            </field>
        </record>
    </sub-category>
    <sub-category name="Therapeutic Interests">
        <record>
            <field name="Therapeutic Group/Interest">
                <importValue>Therapeutic Interest Group Descripti Max [ABCDEFZ]/Therapeutic Interest Description 012 Max [ABCDEFZ]</importValue>
            </field>
        </record>
    </sub-category>
    <sub-category name="Fraud and Misconduct Events">
        <record>
            <field name="Event">
                <importValue>Very Bad Things [VBAD]</importValue>
                <existingValue>Very Bad Things [VBAD]</existingValue>
            </field>
            <field name="Event Date">
                <importValue>10-Jan-2011</importValue>
                <existingValue>01-Sep-2011</existingValue>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record>
            <field name="Event">
                <importValue>Bad Things [BAD]</importValue>
                <existingValue>Bad Things [BAD]</existingValue>
            </field>
            <field name="Event Date">
                <importValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                <existingValue>22-Sep-2011</existingValue>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record>
            <field name="Event">
                <existingValue>Extremely Bad Things [EBAD]</existingValue>
            </field>
            <field name="Event Date">
                <existingValue>14-Sep-2011</existingValue>
            </field>
        </record>
    </sub-category>
    <import-id>30</import-id>
    <row-no>2</row-no>
    <investigator-no>153</investigator-no>
    <clinical-personnel-name>Mrs B B SPECIALIST</clinical-personnel-name>
    <report-footer-message>Report Produced at 28-09-2011 09:42 by Mr Installation</report-footer-message>
    <properties><property key="heading.clinicalPersonnelComparisonReport">Clinical Personnel Comparison Report</property><property key="heading.importId">Import Id</property><property key="heading.recordNo">Record No</property><property key="heading.existingDuplicateClinicalPersonnel">Existing Duplicate Clinical Personnel</property><property key="heading.clinicalPersonnelComparisonReportTitle">This report details the differences which exist between the imported Clinical Personnel and the existing master Clinical Personnel.</property><property key="heading.clinicalPersonnelComparisonReportTitleNoDifferences">No differences exist between the imported Clinical Personnel and the existing master Clinical Personnel.</property><property key="heading.followingClinicalPersonnelDetailsDiffer">The following Clinical Personnel details differ:-</property><property key="heading.clinicalPersonnelDetails">Clinical Personnel Details</property><property key="heading.itemName">Item Name</property><property key="heading.importValue">Import Value</property><property key="heading.existingClinicalPersonnelValue">Existing Clinical Personnel Value</property><property key="heading.addressDetails">Address Details</property><property key="heading.noDifferencesIdentified">No differences identified</property><property key="heading.addressType">Address Type</property><property key="heading.field">Field</property><property key="heading.importAddress">Import Address</property><property key="heading.existingClinicalPersonnelAddress">Existing Clinical Personnel Address</property><property key="heading.fraudMisconduct">Fraud and Misconduct</property><property key="heading.event">Event</property><property key="heading.eventDate">Event Date</property><property key="heading.associatedCentre">Associated Centre</property><property key="heading.importCentre">Import Centre</property><property key="heading.existingClinicalPersonnelCentre">Existing Clinical Personnel Centre</property><property key="heading.specialistsFields">Specialist Fields</property><property key="heading.therapeuticInterests">Therapeutic Interests</property><property key="heading.therapeuticGroupInterest">Therapeutic Group/Interest</property><property key="heading.membershipInformation">Membership Information</property><property key="heading.invMembershipsInformationMembership">Association/Society</property><property key="heading.investigatorNo">Investigator No</property><property key="heading.existingClinicalPersonnelChecklists">Existing Clinical Personnel Checklist(s)</property><property key="heading.checklistNo">Checklist No</property><property key="heading.title">Title</property><property key="heading.description">Description</property><property key="heading.status">Status</property><property key="heading.completedBy">Completed By</property><property key="heading.completedDate">Completed Date</property><property key="heading.question">Question</property><property key="heading.response">Response</property></properties>
</ns2:comparison>
```

(The only edit I've made to the above files is to replace my work's name with "blah")

---

**Update** I have also tried setting `elementFormDefault="qualified"` in the XSD, but that doesn't help (although the generated XML does lose the "ns2" namespace prefix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you create your XSL-FO? Some XSLT transformation? Seems like this transformation expects the document in the default namespace.

If this is so then there's two ways to approch this:

- If you want to keep the XSLT as it is, you have to change the schema to be namespaceless.
- If you're OK to change the XSLT, make it process elements in your namespace instead of empty namespace. Use `elementFormDefault="qualified"` and `attributeFormDefault="unqualified"`, it's a usual practice.

The decision is mainly based on the question - if you care about the namespace of your schema. If you don't, the first way will cost you less effort. Me personally, I'd opt for the second option, I think namespaces to be important.

Yet another way is to keep namespaces but use an XSLT to drop them before rendering with FOP.

Comment: yes, the code is using XSLT and I'm happy to change it. I'll give the second approach a try.

Comment: Unfortunately the second approach did not work for me. In the end I ended up removing the namespace, mainly because I'm on a deadline and this is purely internal to the application so the lack of a namespace doesn't really matter. Thanks